# PySpark & Tensorflow - Dummy encoding string data

Tags: python, apache-spark, keras, pyspark

I want to dummy encode (or similar) data to give it to Keras.

For now, I treat my tabular data with Spark and then train it with Keras.

The thing is I got a column with string data and can't give it directly to Keras, so I need to transform it to integers.

I already did `StringIndexer` + `OneHotEncoding` but the thing is I got a columns of sparse vector and this is not what I want, I mean to give to Keras.

```
data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 23.0, "mak"), (3, "B", -23.0, "kaks"), (3, "a", -22.0, "kaks"), (3, "a", -22.0, "chochon")], ("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"))

data.show()

+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| x1| x2|   x3|     x4|x2_index|x4_index|    x2_vector|    x4_vector|
+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|  1|  a| 23.0|    mak|     0.0|     1.0|(1,[0],[1.0])|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|  3|  B|-23.0|   kaks|     1.0|     0.0|    (1,[],[])|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|  3|  a|-22.0|   kaks|     0.0|     0.0|(1,[0],[1.0])|(2,[0],[1.0])|
|  3|  a|-22.0|chochon|     0.0|     2.0|(1,[0],[1.0])|    (2,[],[])|
+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

Do you have something which to do to give "good data" to keras ?

```
I though something like that : 
+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| x1| x2|   x3|     x4|x2_index|x4_index|    x2_vector|         x4_0|         x4_1|         x4_2|
+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1|  a| 23.0|    mak|     0.0|     1.0|(1,[0],[1.0])|            1|            0|            0|
|  3|  B|-23.0|   kaks|     1.0|     0.0|    (1,[],[])|            0|            1|            0|
|  3|  a|-22.0|   kaks|     0.0|     0.0|(1,[0],[1.0])|            0|            1|            0|
|  3|  a|-22.0|chochon|     0.0|     2.0|(1,[0],[1.0])|            0|            0|            1|
+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

But I don't know if this is the good thing to do too.

Comment: you might be able to use a vector assember and pack all the numeric cols together with the hot-encoded cols into a vector. Either keras can read this vector directly or you'll need to convert it to a numpy array as a first step of your UDF (I assume you're using keras within a UDF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to replicate partially what you have in mind with the `x4` column. I am assuming you want to turn strings into numerics for ML use, and no sparse vectors.

Code

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator

data = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('mak',), ('kaks',), ('kaks',), ('chochon',)], ('x4',))

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='x4', outputCol='x4_index')
indexed = indexer.fit(data).transform(data)

encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=['x4_index'],outputCols=['x4_vector'], dropLast=False)
encoded = encoder.fit(indexed).transform(indexed)

#at this stage, you have
#encoded.show()
#+-------+--------+-------------+
#|     x4|x4_index|    x4_vector|
#+-------+--------+-------------+
#|    mak|     2.0|(3,[2],[1.0])|
#|   kaks|     0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
#|   kaks|     0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
#|chochon|     1.0|(3,[1],[1.0])|
#+-------+--------+-------------+

#further process it one more step to get what you have in mind
def mfunc(row):
    return [row['x4'],row['x4_index']] + list(map(int,row['x4_vector'].toArray().tolist()))

encoded.rdd.map(mfunc).toDF(['x4','x4_index', 'x4_0', 'x4_1', 'x4_2']).show()

#+-------+--------+----+----+----+
#|     x4|x4_index|x4_0|x4_1|x4_2|
#+-------+--------+----+----+----+
#|    mak|     2.0|   0|   0|   1|
#|   kaks|     0.0|   1|   0|   0|
#|   kaks|     0.0|   1|   0|   0|
#|chochon|     1.0|   0|   1|   0|
#+-------+--------+----+----+----+

#alternatively, if you want dense vectors, then use this
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector

def mfunc1(row):
    return [row['x4'],row['x4_index']] + [list(map(int, DenseVector(row['x4_vector'])))]

encoded.rdd.map(mfunc1).toDF(['x4','x4_index', 'x4_dense']).show()

#+-------+--------+---------+
#|     x4|x4_index| x4_dense|
#+-------+--------+---------+
#|    mak|     2.0|[0, 0, 1]|
#|   kaks|     0.0|[1, 0, 0]|
#|   kaks|     0.0|[1, 0, 0]|
#|chochon|     1.0|[0, 1, 0]|
#+-------+--------+---------+
```

I hope one of them works with Keras, and helps you to decide what is "good".

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This is what I want but how to dynamically set columns ? `encoded.rdd.map(mfunc).toDF(['x4','x4_index', 'x4_0', 'x4_1', 'x4_2']).show()` is just converting to fixed 0, 1 and 2 but imagine I got other values like 3 in the index, or just n values ?

Comment: @LaSul Try `encoded.rdd.map(mfunc).toDF().show()` on an nx1 vector and see what you get. A quick example would be deleting the last row then rerun my code to get a 2x1 vector. The algo is smart enough to automatically name the columns for you dynamically. Try it and see how it goes.

Comment: @LaSul P. S. Try encoded.rdd.map().toDF(['x4', 'x4_index']).show() too, you should get what you want with an nx1 vector.